Uniswap Swapping
I have a problem swapping on uniswap. I want to swap token but when I select token I want to swap it says "not enough liquidity". Can anyone help me. It is quite some money in stake. Thanks.

There needs to be liquidity (enough tokens deposited) in the pool smart contract. If it says there is no liquidity on the front end website, then the backend off chain routing system can't find a path for your swap. If it is a live chain, then you will likely need to find another exchange where there is liquidity. If a testnet it could just be the front end isn't connected but that you can can find the pool (and router if you need) to interact directly.

The "not enough liquidity" error on Uniswap generally means that there isn't sufficient liquidity in the pool for the token pair you're trying to swap
